# Add an image/figure under the description of an enumerate(a custom position in the text)

Tags: enumerate

This question might be easily answered, but I have been searching it for a while without any luck. I was wondering if it is able to insert an image at a very specific point of a document, i.e. under the (custom) description of an enumarate list. It is quite complicated to describe, and since an image is 1000 words, here is a screen shot of what I would like to produce with LaTeX:

Original results:

[image]

What I would like to achieve:

[image]

Is this doable?

I am including the code that produced the text in the pictures above.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=20mm, bottom=15mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=16pt,label=\bfseries 02/2016 \textendash \: 02/2019:]
    \item \textbf{This is some random text}\\  Some more text\\
    More text.\\
    More text.
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: don't use \\ to produce line break. Use a blank line instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `enumitem`, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\myIncludeImgInList}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \raisebox{-\height-0.2cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \includegraphics[width=\labelwidth]{#1}}\hspace*{0.2cm}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=16pt,
                    label=\bfseries 02/2016 \textendash \: 02/2019:]
    \item \myIncludeImgInList{example-image}%
          \textbf{This is some random text}\\  Some more text\\
      More text.\\
      More text.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But since the image doesn't take any vertical space in this method (otherwise, it would shift the second line of your text downwards), you would have to add space manually after this block for the thing to come, or it would overlap with the image (if the image is taller than the text at its right). For this reason, I'd rather use a `tabular` inside a `tabularx` environment here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myLeftColumn}[1][1.5]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
    }{%
    \end{tabular}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begingroup % to limit the scope of \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}
  \noindent
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
  %
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace*{1em}}X@{}}
    \begin{myLeftColumn}
      02/2016 \textendash \: 02/2019:\\
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
    \end{myLeftColumn}
    &
    \textbf{This is some random text}\newline
    Some more text\newline
    More text.\newline
    More text.
    \\
    \begin{myLeftColumn}
      04/2019 \textendash \: 05/2019:\\
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{myLeftColumn}
    &
    \textbf{Other text}

    in

    several

    paragraphs. \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

The initial `\arraystretch` setting allows one to tune the vertical spacing between high-level entries, while the optional argument of the `myLeftColumn` environment is for the vertical space between left-column text and image (they are both multiplication factors applied to the normal spacing between two lines of the respective `tabularx` or `tabular` environment).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Fantastic, thank you very very much! Excellent response!

As you said, though, if the image is too big it will overlap with the text below, but resizing a bit the original image (essentially adding some white space around it) does the trick! I will give your other proposal a go to, just to compare, but this answers it! :)